# Mocking bootstrap functions in react tests

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I have a React component with the following in the componentDidMount():

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

which in my Mocha tests, throws the following:

> TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

I have the Sinon package installed, so I thought it might be easy to define a sinon stub() in my test's beforeEach().

I'm open to any solution to this, but since Sinon is already a package I have installed, might be the easiest solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do this simply and didn't need Sinon (although I really would like to explore sinon for other things, looks super useful!)

I added this to my Mocha tests and voila, all tests pass:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    $.fn.tooltip = () => { };
  });
```